# why does mathematica not return the result of the multiplication of a symbolic matrix and a symbolic vector?

Tags: matrix

I am really stuck at a simple problem. Maybe, it is not totally a problem. However, I don't understand why.

I am trying to take the dot product of two expressions.

Here is the code:

```
a = {{Ixx, 0, 0}, {0, Iyy, 0}, {0, 0, Izz}}
b = {{0}, {0}, {Theta1'[t]}}
```

`a.b` should work according to the documentation. I am expecting the result

```
{{0}, {0}, {Izz*Theta1'[t]}}
```

and after `// MatrixForm`, it will be `[0; 0; something]`.

But, after the a.b production, I just get this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just don't use `MatrixForm` for defining matrices. It does not define a matrix; instead it is only for displaying purposes.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i understand the problem. apparently, i should be careful by using MatrixForm.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MatrixForm` is wrapper. It prevent future evaluations. You must have added a `MatrixForm` around `a` and `b` before, that is why.

Try

```
a = {{Ixx, 0, 0}, {0, Iyy, 0}, {0, 0, Izz}}; b = {{0}, {0}, {Theta1'[t]}};
(a.b) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

It looks like you did this before

```
a = MatrixForm@{{Ixx, 0, 0}, {0, Iyy, 0}, {0, 0, Izz}}; 
b = MatrixForm@{{0}, {0}, {Theta1'[t]}};
(a.b)
```

[image]

To see the matrix using `MatrixForm` and also not have to worry about it going into it and causing problems later on, just use `()` like this

```
(a = {{Ixx, 0, 0}, {0, Iyy, 0}, {0, 0, Izz}}) // MatrixForm
(b = {{0}, {0}, {Theta1'[t]}}) // MatrixForm
(c = a.b) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect explanation. It directly works. Thanks a lot.